# Nextjs: The page does not render when the URL is entered directly from the browser, 404 error

Tags: docker, next.js, http-status-code-404

My problem is as follows.

I made a project with Next.js. My project works fine on Local, Local Docker, Heroku and Vercel. However, I have a problem when I go to production environment and publish Docker under the domain. When the address is entered from the browser, the page corresponding to the Router gives 404. But when I navigate through the menu, I don't have a problem. In other words, when the URL is entered directly, it does not render. How can i solve this problem. Domain for those who want to review. Original URL: https://beta.ardictech.com/ and this is Vercel URL: https://ardic-web.vercel.app/

For example, it gives 404 when directly entered with the URL, but when you click on the logo in the upper left and go to the "/" address, the page can be rendered. Or, the pages are rendered while navigating the menu, but if you enter the same address directly or press F5, it does not render.

**next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      polls: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    return config;
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  generateEtags: false,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "tr"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  env: {
    VERSION: process.env.VERSION,
    MODE: process.env.MODE,
    APP_NAME: process.env.APP_NAME,
    HOST: process.env.HOST,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    HOSTNAME: process.env.HOSTNAME,
    PORT: process.env.PORT,
    GA_TRACKING_ID: process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID,
  },
  generateBuildId: async() => {
    return new Date().toDateString();
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: false,
  },
};
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  ui:
    container_name: beta.ardictech.com
    hostname: beta.ardictech.com
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    env_file:
      - .env
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:current-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM base AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build
COPY --from=base /app ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:current-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /build/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /build/public ./public

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the web server in front of the app.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so too. However, when the IP of the deployment on the web server is entered with the local IP (192.168...), it seems that this problem continues.

Comment: That doesn't exclude anything though. It could still be proxying different routes differently.

Comment: I have tested, for example if i click from your index page to technologies (https://ardic-web.vercel.app/technologies/), I have an error. If I enter ths link directly, I have no error. You problem is in the code: actually I think error is triggered because you are doing manipulations with your data when it is not loaded.

Comment: @illiachill I was trying something, due to broken automatic deployment at that time. I fixed it now in Vercel.